# Twig send data to symfony controller from form type

Tags: php, symfony, view, controller, twig

I got the following form type:

```
class AjoutDossierType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nomDossier', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nom du dossier',
                'required' => 'true',
                'attr' => array('pattern' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-&.]{1,255}')
                 ))
            ->add('btnAction', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

And the following modal in my twig view where I use the previous form:

```
{% if dossierForm is not null %}
<div id="ajout-dossier" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Ajout d'un dossier</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {% if dossierForm is defined %}
                {{ form_start(dossierForm, { 'attr': { 'data-toggle':'validator' } }) }}
                    {{ form_row(dossierForm.nomDossier)  }}
                    {{ form_row(dossierForm.btnAction, {'label':'Créer', 'full_name':'dossierVoulu', 'value':'{{getDossierCourant(cheminVoulu)}}' , 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary boutonRangeeGeneral'}}) }}
                    {{ form_rest(dossierForm) }}
                {{ form_end(dossierForm) }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Caractères acceptés</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lettres minuscules et majuscules</li>
                    <li>Chiffres (0-0)</li>
                    <li>Les symboles suivants : (_-&.)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The thing is, I want to send to my controller a value when he clicks on the button that I need to perform different tasks, So I added this:

```
{{ form_row(dossierForm.btnAction, {'label':'Créer', 'full_name':'dossierVoulu', 'value':'{{getDossierCourant(cheminVoulu)}}' , 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary boutonRangeeGeneral'}}) }}
```

This doesn't work but it does on a regular HTML form and I can't find any useful documentation. Is there any way to make it work or another technique to achieve the same results?

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form?  Does this need to be AJAX?  What do you mean by send the controller a value?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: No need for it to be AJAX. I need the 'value' of the name 'dossierVoulu' in my controller when the user clicks on the button. I get it in my controller by doing a POST request like so:
`$dossierVoulu = $request->request->get('dossierVoulu');`

Comment: Okay, that sounds more like an HTML issue.  Just make it a hidden variable that gets submitted with your page, or add it as a hidden field to your Symfony form type, or add it as a button type to your Symfony form type.